# SQL Server 2008 R2 Bulk Insert Logging

Tags: sql-server

I have to build a very large table (hundreds of millions of records) from tab-delimited text files that I created with a parsing script and therefore know to be uniform and correct. I would love to find a way to do this without SQL Server using any processing power or disk space to log the transactions--if something goes wrong, I'm happy if the bulk insert just dies without trying to roll back the table to some earlier state. Is that possible?

I've searched extensively on this question and I find mentions of using a "Simple" Recovery Model, but it sounds like that might be only effective with the first bulk insert, when the table is empty? If it matters, I plan to index after all of the bulk inserts have completed.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Bulk logged** recovery model is the right one for your scenario, which will be doing minimal logging for bulk operation like BULK INSERT, INDEX maintenance operations, etc.... And in SQL Server there is no operation which is non-logged and everything is logged but based on database recovery model the level of logging and transaction log clearing happens. please find the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275(v=sql.110).aspx) which describes various recovery models.

Comment: As Rao Y recommended, I set my empty database to the "Bulk-logged" recovery model. I created a table and bulk inserted 141,245,646 records into an empty table from a 25-gb tab-delimited text file. It took 1 hour and 39 minutes. Now the mdf file is 36.7 gb and the ldf file ballooned to **82 gb**. Is that really as good as I can do?